# Jumi script not executing in mobile tag for mobilejoomla content selector

Tags: php, mobile, joomla, jumi

I am having a bit a frustrating time with the following code and was wondering if anyone can help me out.

I have the follow text in an article in Joomla and am getting strange results.

I'm using Jumi to call some php code, and in the desktop view the called code works.
However when in the mobile code section, it seems that *mobilejoomla* is preventing jumi from executing.

This seems rather weird. Has anyone seen a work-around? Am I missing something?

```
{jumi [functions.php]}
{desktop}
     This JUMI output text shows         
       {jumi [index.php]}
     This writing shows
{/desktop} 
{mobile}
     This JUMI output text shows
       {jumi [mobile_index.php]}
     This writing does NOT show
{/mobile}
```

Basically, I don't want the same content on the mobile view page, to the desktop page.

I am sure my code works, because when I do the following, I still get nothing in the {Mobile} view.

```
{jumi [functions.php]}
{desktop}
     Show some text
{/desktop} 
{mobile}
     This JUMI output text shows
       {jumi [index.php]}
     This writing does NOT show
{/mobile}
```

Different content types doco.
http://www.mobilejoomla.com/documentation/14-extensions/110-mobile-content-extension.html

Thanks in advance.
Steve

Comment: What is ordering of MobileContent and Jumi plugins? Did you try to change "scope" parameter of MobileContent plugin?

Comment: Hi @DenisRyabov, You seem to have pointed me in a direction that may be promising. I didn't know these entries existed. I've tried the plug-in orders, and moving them around too as well as changing the scope from Content Only, to Full Page, but this produces strange results.
The scripts are however executing, but the strange thing is now however, the Mobile and the Desktop tags display (even though the script has run it's course). 
The other weird thing is that the mobile content only displays if the errors are turned on... The plot thickens. 
Oh how fun it is to use third party plugins. haha

Comment: The problem is that MobileContent plugin considers any `{...}` blocks embedded in `{mobile}...{/mobile}` as tags of mobile mode, because of full syntax is like `{mobile}...{iphone}...{xhtml}...{/mobile}`. But `{jumi}` inside `{desktop}` should work.

Comment: So, `{mobile}{jumi [file.php]}{/mobile}` should work if MobileContent plugin is in Full Page scope mode and it is run after Jumi plugin (int this case file.php will be run, but then its output will be removed in desktop mode).

Answer (score 0):

I depend on jumi for lots of small scripts and was having a similar problem. I wanted to add a popup window of an image using sigplus or modals within a script. The plugin wouldn't parse within the jumi call. It would just print the braces and code. I tried a bunch of workarounds (hardcoding the script itself & divs, tables in the joomla content). I finally tried sourcerer for incorporating this script and the embedded code worked.

```
{jumi [myscript.php} with a hardcoded call within the script itself -- to {modal linktoimage/image.gif}image{/modal}
```

doesn't parse the plugin. Runs the script, but just prints "{braces and whatever is inside}"

With sourcerer

```
{source} <? my whole script here including {modal linktoimage/image.gif}clik me{/modal}{/source}?>
```

Works fine. With Sourcerer I had to get used to writing or pasting my script within the joomla content editor instead of calling it from a dir/script.  If I'm way off target remember I am just trying to help.